# Getting bullet physics transform matrix for Opengl

Tags: opengl-3, glm-math, bulletphysics

As of now I am using the below code to get the transform matrix from my rigid body in bullet and apply it to my instance. Now right now it seems to not be updating my rendered cube's transform, my first though is to believe that I'm losing data when creating a glm mat4. So my question is am I converting the data correctly to transform my matrix?

```
for (int i = 0; i < WoodenCrateInstances.size(); i++)
{
    btTransform t;
    WoodenCrateInstances.at(i).asset->body->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(t);
    float mat[16];
    t.getOpenGLMatrix(mat);
    glm::vec3 vec = glm::make_vec3(mat);
    WoodenCrateInstances.at(i).transform = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), vec);
}
```

Comment: superset that also takes every triangle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948060/how-to-apply-bullet-physics-to-drawn-opengl-3d-shapes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the full transform, you should do:

```
btTransform t;

// Get the transform from Bullet and into 't'
WoodenCrateInstances.at(i).asset->body->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(t);

// Convert the btTransform into the GLM matrix using 'glm::value_ptr'
t.getOpenGLMatrix(glm::value_ptr(WoodenCrateInstances.at(i).transform));
```

As you only create a translation matrix at the moment, you loose orientation/rotation, and eventually scale.

Also note, that the matrices returned from Bullet is in world space, so if you have a scene hierachy/graph with the matrices stored as relative transforms to the node's parent node, you might also want to transform the matrix into local space, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

To get the model matrix from Bullet Physics to OpenGL, declare a `btScalar transform[16]`, then query the body motion state. For static objects, use instead `m_rigidBody->getWorldTransform()` because the motion state is not updated for static objects (bug report created on GitHub).

Reformat the model matrix by calling the first utility method `btScalar2mat4()` or call the Bullet Physics method `transform.getOpenGLMatrix(btScalar *array)` returning a pointer to a 16 elements row major array to pass onto the second utility method `glm::mat4 array2mat4(const float* array)`.

```
void Cube::update(glm::mat4 T) {

    /* btScalar transform[16];

    if (m_motionState)
        m_motionState->getModelMatrix(transform); */

    if (m_rigidBody) {
        btTransform transform = m_rigidBody->getWorldTransform();

        m_modelMatrix = btScalar2glmMat4(transform);
        m_modelMatrix = T * m_modelMatrix;

        // if (VERBOSE) printMat4(m_modelMatrix);
    }
}


glm::mat4 btScalar2mat4(btScalar* matrix) {
    return glm::mat4(
        matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], matrix[3],
        matrix[4], matrix[5], matrix[6], matrix[7],
        matrix[8], matrix[9], matrix[10], matrix[11],
        matrix[12], matrix[13], matrix[14], matrix[15]);
}


glm::mat4 array2mat4(const float* array) {     // OpenGL row major

    glm::mat4 matrix;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = array[i + j];
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Done, thank you for your useful advice!

Comment: Great answer, very complete, just what I was looking for.